# Font correction in report

Tags: fonts, bold, report

In my report, some part of the body is bold and some are not. That is, chapters are bold, sections are not and subsections are bold, not in the contents but on the body, how can i set it fully to normal.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm guessing the definition of the appearance of subsection-level headers is at fault. But unless you provide a compilable example that reproduces this issue, there's no way to verify this conjecture.